# Constraint on columns based on single column not firing

Tags: postgresql

I made a constraint where to mark the column `completed` to `true` some of the other columns would have to have a value.

But for some reason the constraint does not complain when I leave a specified column blank when `completed` is marked `true`. I have also purposely inserted NULL a specified column and still no constraint.

Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE info (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at timestamptz default current_timestamp,
  posted_by text REFERENCES users ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  title character varying(31),
  lat numeric,
  lng numeric,
  contact_email text,
  cost money,
  description text,
  active boolean DEFAULT false,
  activated_date date,
  deactivated_date date,
  completed boolean DEFAULT false,
  images jsonb,

  CONSTRAINT columns_null_check CHECK (
  (completed = true
  AND posted_by != NULL
  AND title != NULL
  AND lat != NULL
  AND lng != NULL
  AND contact_email != NULL
  AND cost != NULL
  AND description != NULL
  AND images != NULL) OR completed = false)
);
```

Comment: Try use `IS NOT NULL` but not `!= NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Chapter 9. Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparison.html):

> To check whether a value is or is not null, use the predicates:
>
> ```
> expression IS NULL
> expression IS NOT NULL
> ```
>
> or the equivalent, but nonstandard, predicates:
>
> ```
> expression ISNULL
> expression NOTNULL
> ```

Therefore you can not use `value != NULL` to check null values, you can only use `value IS NULL` and `value IS NOT NULL`.

For boolean values they are the same:

> Boolean values can also be tested using the predicates
>
> ```
> boolean_expression IS TRUE
> boolean_expression IS NOT TRUE
> boolean_expression IS FALSE
> boolean_expression IS NOT FALSE
> boolean_expression IS UNKNOWN
> boolean_expression IS NOT UNKNOWN
> ```

Comment: I would crop out the `unknown` and `not unknown` example. While different in the spec, PostgreSQL treats them the same. The distinction here is potentially confusing.